# Problem with ProRender making things transparent (2.82a)

Tags: rendering, radeon-prorender-render-engine

I installed the AMD's ProRender render engine for Blender, but all the renders using the GPU come off as a faulty render.

I updated my drivers, restarted the PC, and run a test on my hardware, and everything was fine. My hardware is an AMD FX8350 and a R9 270.

This is how the images look when rendering

Render with only CPU

[image: Render with only CPU]

Render with CPU + GPU

[image: Render with CPU + GPU]

Any help with the problem would be apreciated

Edit: [Here's a gif](https://gyazo.com/8cb0de97faf1db6155d784350e9a9304) if it helps